# Swift: Repeating letters turn to a number in a String

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have a String, lets say

```
var abc : String = "aaaabbbbbbbccddd"
```

I need an algorithm on how to change these repeating letters to the number of repeating letters (if there is more than 2 in a row), so that the given string would become

```
abc = "a4b7ccd3"
```

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with this string :

```
let abc : String = "aaaabbbbbbbccddde"
```

And have the output in a new variable

```
var result = ""
```

Let's use an index to go through the characters in the string

```
var index = abc.startIndex

while index < abc.endIndex {
    //There is already one character :
    let char = abc[index]
    var count = 0

    //Let's check the following characters, if any
    repeat {
        count += 1
        index = abc.index(after: index)
    } while index < abc.endIndex && abc[index] == char

    //and update the result accordingly 
    result += count < 3 ?
        String(repeating: char, count: count) :
        String(char) + String(count)
}
```

And here is the result :

```
print(result)  //a4b7ccd3e
```

Comment: Minor remark: Using `repeat {} while` for the inner loop can shorten it slightly and avoid the duplicate index increment.

Comment: @MartinR: Cool idea! I'll update the answer with your suggestion