# Task from the interview. How we would solve it?

Tags: swift, run-length-encoding

Convert String in this way

```
let initialString = "atttbcdddd"
// result must be like this "at3bcd4"
```

But repetition must be more than 2. For example, if we have "aa" the result will be "aa", but if we have "aaa", the result will be "a3"

One more example:

```
let str = "aahhhgggg"
//result "aah3g4"
```

My try:

```
func encrypt(_ str: String) -> String {

    let char = str.components(separatedBy: "t") //must input the character
    var count = char.count - 1
    var string = ""
    string.append("t\(count)")
    return string
}
```

if i input "ttttt" it will return "t5" but i should input the character

Comment: Please try something and ask if you can't do .

Comment: i have already tried

Comment: Show the code you've tried

Comment: The post has been updated

Comment: Clearly the general approach is to walk the string writing each character into a new string (with appropriate adjustments). Where is your code that does that?

Comment: @StanislavMarynych you can check with my answer I have updated it.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535344/2907715

Comment: @Carpsen90: Indeed! – I knew that I had seen this before, but hadn't found it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [“Run-length encoding”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). Note that this is *not* an encryption!

Here is a possible implementation (explanations inline):

```
func runLengthEncode(_ str: String) -> String {
    var result = ""
    var pos = str.startIndex // Start index of current run
    while pos != str.endIndex {
        let char = str[pos]
        // Find index of next run (or `endIndex` if there is none):
        let next = str[pos...].firstIndex(where: { $0 != char }) ?? str.endIndex
        // Compute the length of the current run:
        let length = str.distance(from: pos, to: next)
        // Append compressed output to the result:
        result.append(length <= 2 ? String(repeating: char, count: length) : "\(char)\(length)")
        pos = next // ... and continue with next run
    }
    return result
}
```

Examples:

```
print(runLengthEncode("atttbcdddd")) // at3bcd4
print(runLengthEncode("aahhhgggg"))  // aah3g4
print(runLengthEncode("abbbaaa"))    // ab3a3
```

Answer (score 1):

**Checkout this :**

```
func convertString(_ input : String) -> String {
    let allElements = Array(input)
    let uniqueElements = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: allElements)) as! [Character]
    var outputString = ""

    for uniqueChar in uniqueElements  {
        var count = 0
        for char in allElements {
            if char == uniqueChar {
                count+=1
            }
        }
        if count > 2 {
            outputString += "\(uniqueChar)\(count)"
        } else if count == 2 {
            outputString += "\(uniqueChar)\(uniqueChar)"
        } else {
            outputString += "\(uniqueChar)"
        }
    }
    return outputString
}
```

**Input** :  `convertString("atttbcdddd")`

**Output** : `at3bcd4`

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it before for one of the interview and also I think you too :). However, very simple way to do it is just go through step by step of code.

```
let initialString = "atttbcdddd"
var previousChar: Character = " "
var output = ""
var i = 1 // Used to count the repeated charaters
var counter = 0 // To check the last character has been reached

//Going through each character
for char in initialString {

    //Increase the characters counter to check the last element has been reached. If it is, add the character to output.
    counter += 1
    if previousChar == char { i += 1 }
    else {
        output = output + (i == 1 ? "\(previousChar)" : "\(previousChar)\(i)")
        i = 1
    }
    if initialString.count == counter {
        output = output + (i == 1 ? "\(previousChar)" : "\(previousChar)\(i)")
    }
    previousChar = char
}
let finalOutput = output.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
print(finalOutput)
```

Comment: why do you need to add space before for previous character??

Comment: Character type is not initialized by empty string so I created prevousChar with space.

Answer (score 1):

```
let initialString = "atttbcdddd"
let myInitialString = initialString + " "

var currentLetter: Character = " "
var currentCount = 1
var answer = ""

for (_, char) in myInitialString.enumerated(){
    if char == currentLetter {
        currentCount += 1
    } else {
        if currentCount > 1 {
            answer += String(currentCount)
        }
        answer += String(char)
        currentCount = 1
        currentLetter = char
   }
}
print(answer)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use reduce here.

```
func exp(_ s : String, _ term: String) -> String{ //term_inator: Any Char not in the Sequence.

guard let first = s.first  else {return ""}

return """
\(s.dropFirst().appending(term).reduce(("\(first)",1)){ r, c in
let t = c == r.0.last!
let tc =  t  ? r.1 : 0
let tb =  t  ? ""  : "\(c)"
let ta =  t  ? ""  :   r.1 > 2 ? "\(r.1)"  : r.1 == 2 ?  "\(r.0.last!)" : ""
return (r.0 + ta + tb, tc + 1)
}.0.dropLast())
"""}

print(exp(initialString, " "))

let initialString = "abbbaaa" // ab3a3
let initialString = "aahhhgggg" // aah3g4
let initialString = "aabbaa" //  aabbaa
```